# Error build-impl.xml:1100.The module has not been deployed

Tags: javascript, java, html

The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details. BUILD FAILED (total time: 6 seconds).Error-build-impl.xml:1100.I have already tried adding context.xml file and jar files are complete.

Answer (score 0):

If your IDE is NetBeans， you can try to right click project and choose "clean and build". If this do no use, you can try to delete domain in glassfish, an get a new domain by netbeans. Good luck!

Comment: when i did "clean and build",it is showing build successful but when i run,then again its showing build failed.Please help